# AWS Route53 NS Change

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, nameservers

I have a very weird issue, I have a domain hosted on AWS Route53 `davi.codes` I changed the NameServers to point to the WordPress NameServers over a week ago but here is the weird thing, when I check on the records on ICCAN Who Is I get that the NameServers are still the AWS ones but when I check on Route53 I see the WordPress NameServer.

Anyone have any idea of what I can do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: from where did you purchase the domain ? was it AWS or 3rd-party ?

Comment: I purchased from AWS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration for each of your domains now has the names of the name servers for the hosted zone that you deleted. To update name servers, you need to:

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon Route 53 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/.
2. Get the names of the name servers for the applicable hosted zone.
3. In the navigation pane, choose Registered Domains.
4. Choose the name of the domain that you want to change name servers for.
5. Choose Add/Edit Name Servers.
6. Change the names of the name servers to the name servers that you got in step 2, and save your changes.

Source: [HERE](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=774532#774532)

Comment: Already done that, but still not propagating. Screenshot is here. https://snag.gy/8JGDNX.jpg any other ideas for how to troubleshoot?

Comment: These instructions are wrong for the problem in the question, because at step 6 is where you supply the third party name servers.  You cannot edit NS in the hosted zone. (Well, you technically *can*, but it doesn't do what you are trying to accomplish.  The only time you can meaningfully edit these is when you are rebranding the Route 53 nameservers as white label servers... which is not what you are doing.)

Comment: @davi_singh Check the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/5l6ot8n. You need to click on "Add or edit name servers" to change the NS records.

Answer (score 0):

If still problem exist then there is another problem.
Delete the hosted zone under Route 53 in aws console. and repeat the above steps again.

Your issue will get resolved